# Error when adjusting CIFilter value by slider

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, filter, swiftui

I am new to swift, when I adjust the `CIFilter` value (intensity here) by the slider. The app will crush. I have found much of the post but still cannot fix the problem.

I have found the problem, which is located at `filter.setValue($sliderValue, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)`, without the `$`, the filtered image will not be updated in real time. Is there any other way to update the filtered image according to the slider value?

Below is the code, and the error message by the simulator

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image:UIImage?
    var selectedSource: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = selectedSource
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent:self)
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker
        init(parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image = uiImage
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var image: UIImage? = nil
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false
    @State private var selectedImageSource = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    @State private var placeHolderImage = Image("")
    @State private var filteredImage = Image("")
    @State private var sliderValue: Double = 10.0
    
    let context = CIContext()
    let filter = CIFilter.sepiaTone()
    
    var body: some View {

        
        VStack {
            placeHolderImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
//                .frame(width: abs(400), height: abs(350))
            Spacer()
            filteredImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
//                .frame(width: abs(400), height: abs(350))
            
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...20)
                HStack {
                    Button("Camera") {
                        selectedImageSource = .camera
                        showingImagePicker = true
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    
                    
                    Button("Library") {
                        selectedImageSource = .photoLibrary
                        showingImagePicker = true
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    
                    
                    Button("SepiaTone") {
                        filter.setValue($sliderValue, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
                        if let cgi = image!.cgImage {
                            let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgi)
                            filter.inputImage=ciImage
                            guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else {return}
                            if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
                                let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
                                filteredImage = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                            }else {
                                print("Failed to create CGImage")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: {
            placeHolderImage = (image == nil) ? Image("") : Image(uiImage: image!)
            
        }){
            ImagePicker(image: self.$image, selectedSource: selectedImageSource)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
CoreSimulator 857.13 - Device: iPhone 14 Pro (11877198-13B9-4683-9863-774756C33AD0) - Runtime: iOS 16.1 (20B72) - DeviceType: iPhone 14 Pro
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__SwiftValue doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: Generally since `filteredImage` is `@State` it should update. But there are many other issues with your code. First of all it may take a while to process an image, while you expect an immediate reaction. Best is separate image processing and use async/await to wait for it. Secondly, the whole algorithm you use for image processing is very resource consuming: it's expensive to convert CIImage to CGIMage, and CGImage to CIImage conversion is also not free. So if your underlying image is CGImage, consider processing it directly.

Answer (score -1):

Just add `onChange` modifier and perform filtering inside separate method

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var image: UIImage? = nil
    @State private var showingImagePicker = false
    @State private var selectedImageSource = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    @State private var placeHolderImage = Image("")
    @State private var filteredImage = Image("")
    @State private var sliderValue: Double = 10.0
    
    @State private var context = CIContext()
    @State private var filter = CIFilter.sepiaTone()
    
    var body: some View {

        
        VStack {
            placeHolderImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
//                .frame(width: abs(400), height: abs(350))
            Spacer()
            filteredImage
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
//                .frame(width: abs(400), height: abs(350))
            
            Spacer()
            VStack {
                Slider(value: $sliderValue, in: 0...20)
                HStack {
                    Button("Camera") {
                        selectedImageSource = .camera
                        showingImagePicker = true
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    
                    
                    Button("Library") {
                        selectedImageSource = .photoLibrary
                        showingImagePicker = true
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    
                    
                    Button("SepiaTone") {
                        handleSlider(sliderValue: sliderValue)
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: sliderValue, perform: handleSlider(sliderValue:))
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingImagePicker, onDismiss: {
            placeHolderImage = (image == nil) ? Image("") : Image(uiImage: image!)
            
        }){
            ImagePicker(image: self.$image, selectedSource: selectedImageSource)
        }
    }
    
    func handleSlider(sliderValue: Double) {
        filter.setValue(sliderValue, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
        if let cgi = image!.cgImage {
            let ciImage = CIImage(cgImage: cgi)
            filter.inputImage=ciImage
            guard let outputImage = filter.outputImage else {return}
            if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent) {
                let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
                filteredImage = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            }else {
                print("Failed to create CGImage")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: there's no such thing as "displaying CIImage directly" - CIImage is just description of the image, it needs to be converted to pixels (i.e. CGImage) to get displayed. Also there's no such thing as converting CIImage to UIImage - the UIIMage is simply a container for either CIImage or CGIMage